# Grep ignores part of my pattern?

Tags: grep

I have a nice `bash/zenity` script that I use to check/update a number of git repos and report the status of each like this - showing only one sample repo here:

```
zenity --class=CheckGit --info title="Check git updates" --text="\n \
<b>MY-GIT-REPO:</b> $(cd "/home/ME/.local/share/git/MY-GIT-REPO" && git pull | grep -E '(up-to-date|changed)')"
```

It was working well until I encountered an error due to a change in one of the local files, which resulted in a blank line for that repo.

Terminal output was like this:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    xxx/yyy
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

So I modified the grep command like this: `grep -E '(up-to-date|changed|error)'` to also display such messages. But to my surprise it still refused to show anything.

As a novice in bash scripting I don't understand what is causing this. How come grep displays lines containing the words "up-to-date" or "changed" but not "error"?.. Does this word have a special meaning then? In that case how can I make it display an error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git writes its errors to stderr, so you don't miss out on them if you redirect the normal output (to a file, or in your case pipe it into a program).

You can try:

```
zenity --class=CheckGit --info title="Check git updates" --text="\n \
<b>MY-GIT-REPO:</b> $(cd "/home/ME/.local/share/git/MY-GIT-REPO" && git pull 2>&1 | grep -E '(up-to-date|changed|error)')"
```

Comment: Thanks! But there's something strange: I can't reproduce that error message again using the base git pull command after a local change. So I couldn't test if your suggestion will display the error message in my zenity window. Can you please confirm that leaving grep to look for "up-to-date" or "changed" only as you suggest will result in displaying any error messages if the status cannot reported as "up-to-date" or "changed"?

Comment: @Sadi You should check for "error" as well, otherwise these get filtered out by the `grep`

Comment: OK, thanks. I couldn't get git to give me such an "error" message again as it did in the morning (no matter what changes I did locally) but in the end I've managed to get a "fatal" message ;-) So I've also learned that this is another word to look for ;-)